# How could I unit test this code?

Tags: junit, mockito

```
 putS3File(path, name, file);

    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            retryUploadToDir(today, currentHour, subDirectory, file, name, path);
        }
    }, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I am looking to unit test the runnable logic along with the computation inside it

Comment: What is this function doing ? Why does it seem challenging to unit test it ?

Comment: Please correct the formatting. The question is not realy clear.  Do you just want to test the function you are calling? In a unit test you would typically stub this called function, thus you would just test that an unconditional call happens.

Comment: If you're in Java 8, than the `void run()` method could easily be a public static method somewhere that you pass to `schedule` as `() -> staticMethod(...)` - then you can test the static method and not worry about testing the `executor.schedule` piece.